# Apply 3D rotation to iPhone view

Tags: iphone, uiview, 3d, rotation

I would like apply a 3D rotation on a view (in particular to a UILabel) in iPhone. What's the simplest way to do this?

A code example will be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform

Comment: Thanks Brad. Do you think I should delete this one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For 2D rotation use:

```
//rotate label in 45 degrees
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI/4 );
```

For 3D transformations see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301067/iphone-animation-why-does-rotating-a-uilabel-around-x-axis-cut-off-its-bottom-ha):

```
CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians(90.0f), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
// flipping view along axis
// this will rotate view in 3D along any axis 

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DRotate(self.layer.transform, 3.14, 1.0, 0.0,0.0);
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:100];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.08];
self.layer.transform=_3Dt;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swft 3 example

```
let rotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(myView.layer.transform, CGFloat.pi, 1, 0, 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.myView.layer.transform = rotationTransform
}
```